# New Google DocumentsList API .NET Client?

Tags: .net, google-docs-api

Has anyone used the google-gdata "new DocumentsList API"?

I am trying to retrieve a list of documents and I am having problems with authentication.

Using the Google.GData.Documents classes works fine, but when I try to use then newer Google.GData.Docs in a similar fashion I get a 401.

If it helps, I have noticed that my email address doesn't get appended to the url, as it does when I use Google.GData.Documents.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Code as Requested:

```
[Authorize]
public void ListAsync()
{
    string requestorId = "";
    if (Session["email"] != null)
    {
        // get a documents list for the user that logged in
        requestorId = Session["email"].ToString();
    }

    // create an OAuth factory to use
    GOAuthRequestFactory requestFactory = new GOAuthRequestFactory("writely", APPLICATION_NAME);
    requestFactory.ConsumerKey = "XXX";
    requestFactory.ConsumerSecret = "YYY";

    DocsService service = new DocsService(APPLICATION_NAME);

    // this way does work
    //service.setUserCredentials("username", "password");

    // this way doesn't work
    service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;

    Uri queryUri = new Uri("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full");

    service.AsyncOperationCompleted += DocsQueryCompleted;
    AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
    service.QueryFeedAync(queryUri, DateTime.MinValue, this);
}
```

Comment: Post your code. Remove any private information and use example values in their place.  Once you have code in your question I will reverse my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

The Google.GData.Docs library was an experiment and it has actually been retired, while the Google.GData.Documents has been recently updated to implement all parts of version 3 of the Documents List API.

Check the new docs together with all new sample code at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/

Answer (score 0):

```
        OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();            
        parameters.ClientId = CLIENT_ID;
        parameters.ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET;
        parameters.RedirectUri = REDIRECT_URI;
        parameters.Scope = SCOPE;
        string authorizationUrl = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);
```

Try to get auth token with authorizationUrl. Paste it in web browser. And then...
Use Token As strToken like that.

```
        parameters.AccessCode = strToken;
        OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);
        string accessToken = parameters.AccessToken;
        string refreshToken = parameters.RefreshToken;
```

U have all information now.

```
        OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();            
        parameters.ClientId = CLIENT_ID;
        parameters.ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET;
        parameters.RedirectUri = REDIRECT_URI;
        parameters.Scope = SCOPE;
        parameters.AccessToken= accessToken;
        parameters.RefreshToken= refreshToken;

        GOAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory = new GOAuth2RequestFactory(null, "MyDocumentsListIntegration-v1", parameters);
        Serv = new DocumentsService("MyDocumentsListIntegration-v1");
        Serv.RequestFactory = requestFactory;
```

This code must work.